# How to find organization name with tshark

Tags: ip, wireshark, whois, tshark

How can I configure `tshark` to display the `OrgName` of the source or destination IP?

This command produces empty lines

```
tshark -lq -T fields -e ip.geoip.src_org
```

and so does this command

```
tshark -lq -T fields -e whois.answer
```

Answer (score 2):

The only solution found yet is to pipe IP to `whois` command:

`jwhois` is faster than `whois` (test it with `time [cmd]` )

```
#!/bin/bash

tshark -T fields -e ip.addr -E aggregator=" " -l| |sed "s/192.168.1.39//;s/^[ ]*//" |  while read i
do
echo " "
echo "$i" 
jwhois $i | grep -i 'orgname\|country\|netrange' | sed 's/^[ ]*//' 
done
```